# Flutter background message

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uydxg.jpg)

I was doing call program via sip pracatoli using abto_voip_sdk.
in order to receive incoming calls from the background to the app
`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);` I used.

After getting the permission of the SDK, the name of the app is missing without the app mark and the buttons in the app are not being clicked.
How can I fix this?

I added the necessary permissions
But it didn't help